# Get the exact value of language column from a table instead of pk

Tags: mysql

To export a table with the column language in it, what can be used to get the full value of the language used?

With the below code i am getting the pk value of the language:

INSERT_UPDATE TableName; column 1[unique=true];language;createdtime; modificationtime "#% impex.exportItems( ""select {pk} from {TableName} "", Collections.EMPTY_MAP, Collections.singletonList( Item.class ), true, true, -1, -1 );"

Comment: No, you get a syntax error if you run the above in mysql. The underlying database may be mysql, but you are using some kind of a programming language to access mysql and execute an sql statement.

Comment: Hi, the below suggested query executed. Yea though it was for sql but had to excute it in hybris console with this pattern to get the export of it through this impex. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to link the table from where you want to export the data with the language table and use the column name that has been used in that language table with proper attributes in order to get the value

For example:

INSERT_UPDATE TableName; column 1[unique=true];language(name[lang=en])[unique=true];createdtime;modificationtime "#% impex.exportItems( ""select {k.pk} from {TableName as k JOIN LanguageTable as L ON {k.language}={L.pk}} "", Collections.EMPTY_MAP, Collections.singletonList( Item.class ), true, true, -1, -1 );"